Androidx nuget package doesn't work when creating a .NET android app with visual studio
No matter what I try, I can't get androidx to work in my .NET android app project in visual studio. I have tried different controls and none work. I wish to use the recycler view. I get different error messages:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Custom controls disabled. There was an internal issue with the rendering process.

this is the error that shows up in the xml preview
This is what I did

Created a new .NET android project in visual studio
Installed androidx from nuget
Added androidx control (in this case recycler view) to my activity_main.xml
XML preview shows red screen with "show error" button

